# Why does my connection to Google Analytics fail in AWS-Databricks, but not in other environments?

Tags: python, google-analytics, network-programming, devops, databricks

I'm attempting to pull Google Analytics data from within databricks using [google's `google-analytics-data` package](https://pypi.org/project/google-analytics-data/). I'm using an [example script from google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py#3_setup_the_sample) that works fine locally and in other remote environments, but then fails in Databricks with the following trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in _conn_request(self, conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
   1345                 if conn.sock is None:
-> 1346                     conn.connect()
   1347                 conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in connect(self)
   1121 
-> 1122         address_info = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   1123         for family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr in address_info:

/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    747     addrlist = []
--> 748     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    749         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ServerNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4478422> in <module>
     76 
     77 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 78   main()

<command-4478422> in main()
     72 def main():
     73   analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
---> 74   response = get_report(analytics)
     75   print_response(response)
     76 

<command-4478422> in get_report(analytics)
     40           'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
     41           'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
---> 42           'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}]
     43         }]
     44       }

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    132                 elif positional_parameters_enforcement == POSITIONAL_WARNING:
    133                     logger.warning(message)
--> 134             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    135 
    136         return positional_wrapper

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py in execute(self, http, num_retries)
    912             method=str(self.method),
    913             body=self.body,
--> 914             headers=self.headers,
    915         )
    916 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py in _retry_request(http, num_retries, req_type, sleep, rand, uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
    205         if exception:
    206             if retry_num == num_retries:
--> 207                 raise exception
    208             else:
    209                 continue

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py in _retry_request(http, num_retries, req_type, sleep, rand, uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
    174         try:
    175             exception = None
--> 176             resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
    177         # Retry on SSL errors and socket timeout errors.
    178         except _ssl_SSLError as ssl_error:

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py in new_request(uri, method, body, headers, redirections, connection_type)
    157             _LOGGER.info('Attempting refresh to obtain '
    158                          'initial access_token')
--> 159             credentials._refresh(orig_request_method)
    160 
    161         # Clone and modify the request headers to add the appropriate

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py in _refresh(self, http)
    747         """
    748         if not self.store:
--> 749             self._do_refresh_request(http)
    750         else:
    751             self.store.acquire_lock()

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py in _do_refresh_request(self, http)
    778         resp, content = transport.request(
    779             http, self.token_uri, method='POST',
--> 780             body=body, headers=headers)
    781         content = _helpers._from_bytes(content)
    782         if resp.status == http_client.OK:

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py in request(http, uri, method, body, headers, redirections, connection_type)
    280     return http_callable(uri, method=method, body=body, headers=headers,
    281                          redirections=redirections,
--> 282                          connection_type=connection_type)
    283 
    284 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in request(self, uri, method, body, headers, redirections, connection_type)
   1707                 else:
   1708                     (response, content) = self._request(
-> 1709                         conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey,
   1710                     )
   1711         except Exception as e:

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in _request(self, conn, host, absolute_uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
   1422             auth.request(method, request_uri, headers, body)
   1423 
-> 1424         (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
   1425 
   1426         if auth:

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in _conn_request(self, conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
   1351             except socket.gaierror:
   1352                 conn.close()
-> 1353                 raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
   1354             except socket.error as e:
   1355                 errno_ = e.args[0].errno if isinstance(e.args[0], socket.error) else e.errno

ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at oauth2.googleapis.com
```

I originally thought it was a proxy issue, but I can also `dig` the URL from the trace no problem with my current network configuration from within databricks:

```
%sh dig oauth2.googleapis.com
```

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.13-Ubuntu <<>> oauth2.googleapis.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 51610
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: cdebff11af82f9f35ad9acb36064bf0e97dc635743627347 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;oauth2.googleapis.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
oauth2.googleapis.com.  226 IN  A   216.58.192.234

;; Query time: 125 msec
;; SERVER: X.X.X.X#X
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 31 18:27:26 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 94
```

Is there something with the way Databricks executes python code that can cause connection errors like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a proxy issue... Even though `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` were set in the shell I still needed to define them with python.

```py
import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = "some.fake.proxy:port"
os.environ['https_proxy'] = "some.fake.proxy:port"
```